# Angular D3 TopoJSON: mouseover tooltip coordinates wrong

Tags: html, typescript, d3.js, coordinates, topojson

I am trying to implement a `div` tooltip on mouseover for counties in a TopoJSON map of the United States, using D3 on a page built in Angular.

I have tried every combination of the x/y coordinates available in the D3 mouseover event, as well as some combinations suggested online (`D3.pointer`, `Element.getBoundingClientRect`, etc.), but no matter what I do the tooltip seems to fall at incorrect coordinates, offset from my mouse and not necessarily by the same degree at each location on the `svg`.

Is there a proper way to do this? Examples of code are below. The relevant portion is within `this.counties.on("mouseover", ...)`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row g-0">
  <div class="container" id="mapContainer">
    <svg id="map"></svg>
    <div id="tooltip">TESTING</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mapContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
    this.svg = d3.select("#map")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("width", "100%")

    this.g = this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("id", "g")

    this.zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [960, 600]])
      .on("zoom", (event, d) => {
        let {transform} = event
        this.g.attr("transform", transform)
        this.g.attr("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k)
      })

    this.counties = this.g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("fill", "#DFDFDF")
      .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.25")
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(topojson.feature(this.topography, this.topography["objects"]["counties"])["features"])
      .join("path")
      .attr("id", function(d) {return d["id"]})
      .attr('d', this.path)
      .attr("fill", "#DFDFDF")
      .on("mousemove", (event, d) => {

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", `${d3.pointer(event)[0]}px`)
          .style("top", `${d3.pointer(event)[1]}px`)

      })

      // PER DERISTNOCHDA'S SUGGESTION
      .on("mousemove", (event, d) => {

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", `${event.pageY}px`)
          .style("top", `${event.pageX}px`)

      })
```

A few screenshots of results, e.g., when the cursor is in Maine in the top-right:

[image]

And when the cursor is in Arizona in the bottom-left:

[image]

Comment: Since your `#tooltip` is placed absolutely, you should try using `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` instead of the coordinates transformed relative to the events target by `d3.pointer`.

Comment: @deristnochda I tried to implement this (code edited into the TypeScript section above), but this also gives me a tooltip that is not actually near my cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `div#tooltip`'s position absolute with respect to the page, not its parent. So you can **remove this from your CSS:**

```
/* remove this */
#mapContainer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also you should use  `event.pageX` for `left` and `event.pageY` for `top`.

The problem is that you've swapped `x` and `y` values.

Relevant code change:

```
 .style("left", `${event.pageX}px`)
 .style("top", `${event.pageY}px`)
```

Comment: The x-y swap was a typo, but this still does not work — tooltip is offset very far to the right and runs off screen.

Comment: @OJT I missed that detail, remove `#mapContainer { position: relative; }` from your CSS.